# Select last child in parent via mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle: http://liveweave.com/ZwZPMA
(Simplified fiddle is provided at bottom of post as a snippet. This one is to show you its usage)

I'm working on a web design application and ran into a problem.

Now I know a few ways to select an element's children:

```
$(element *)

$(element).children()
```

However those are just ways of grabbing an element's direct descendants.

However I want to select the element I click regardless of how it's a descendant of it's main parent/container (For example mine being `#dynamic-storage`).

Therefore this method here will not work...

```
$("#dynamic-storage *").children().children().children()
```

I know I can use `$(".selected").children().length >= 0` which will check to see if my selected element has any children.

```
if ( $(".selected").children().length <= 0 ) {
  console.log("no children"); 
  return false;
} else if ( $(".selected").children().length >= 0 ) {
  console.log("yes children");
  return false;
}
```

Here's the simplified fiddle.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Draggable FunctionBar
  $(".functionbar").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: ".handlesbar"
  });

  // Select Elements
  var SelectElements = function() {
    $("#dynamic-storage *").children().children().children().on("mouseup touchend", function() {
      if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
      }

      $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
  };
  // Clear Selection
  var ClearSelection = function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  };
  SelectElements();
});
```

```css
/* Body */
#dynamic-storage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* FunctionBar */
.functionbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 998;
}

.functionbar .handlesbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  font: 24px arial;
  text-align: center;
  background: hsla(180, 0%, 0%, .75);
  word-spacing: 12px;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
       -o-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.functionbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: hsl(180, 0%, 90%);
}

.functionbar .active {
  color: #9cf;
}

.functionbar .hide {
  display: none;
}

/* Dialog Sec */
.functionbar .reveal {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.functionbar .reveal, .functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea {
  font-family: arial;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea, #change-selected-tag, #confirm-style {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000;
}

#dynamic-storage .selected {
  outline: 2px dotted #69f;
}

/* Addable Elements */
.functionbar .addcontent {
  text-align: center;
}

.functionbar .addcontent .element, .functionbar .editcontent .element {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.67);
  color: #262B2F;
}
.functionbar .element:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.functionbar .element .fa {
  font-size: 26px;
}
.functionbar .element h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/poly/css/application.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dynamic-storage">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__col--7">
          <div class="centered grid__col--8">
            <p>
              &nbsp;
            </p>
            <h1 class="headline-primary--grouped">Take a look at this amazing headline</h1>
            <h2 class="headline-secondary--grouped selected">Don't forget about the subtitle</h2>
            <p>This is a typical paragraph for the UI Kit. <a href="#">Here is what a link might look like</a>. The typical font family for this kit is Helvetica Neue.  This kit is intended for clean and refreshing web layouts. No jazz hands here, just the essentials to make dreams come true, with minimal clean web design. The kit comes fully equipped with everything from full responsive media styling to buttons to form fields. <em>I enjoy using italics as well from time to time</em>. Fell free to create the most amazing designs ever with this kit. I truly hope you enjoy not only the kit but this amazing paragraph as well. :)</p>
            <blockquote>You know what really gets me going? A really nice set of block quotes.  That's right, block quotes that say, "Hey, I'm an article you want to read and nurture."</blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid__col--4">
          <h4>Offcanvas Menu</h4>
          <div class="offcanvas">
            <span class="icn--close">
              <b class="srt">close</b>
            </span>
            <ul class="menu" role="navigation">
              <a class="menu__link" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="menu__link" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a class="menu__link" href="#">Link 3</a>
              <a class="menu__link--end" href="#">Link 4</a>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you simplify example to minimalistic sample to make your expected behaviour more clear? I'm not sure to understand what you are looking for. On `#dynamic-storage` mousedown, what is the 'last children' you are expecting to get?

Comment: `$(element *)` is not the same as `$(element ).children()` ...first returns children *and* every element inside children also

Comment: Do you mean like that : http://liveweave.com/86x4Mu

Comment: Yes that's correct. I forgot about the :target selector. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually trying to get the clicked target. The event object has the element that triggered the event in one of its property, the `target` property.

So, by having the event as an argument of the function, you're able to select the clicked element byt doing `$(event.target)`. Just note that you have to bind the event on the parent element, in this case : `$('#dynamic-storage')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Draggable FunctionBar
  $(".functionbar").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: ".handlesbar"
  });

  // Select Elements
  var SelectElements = function() {
    $("#dynamic-storage").on("mouseup touchend", function(e) { //Pass the event
      if ( $(".selected").is(":visible") ) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
      }

      // Target the element
      $(e.target).addClass("selected");
    });
  };
  // Clear Selection
  var ClearSelection = function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  };
  SelectElements();
});
```

```css
/* Body */
#dynamic-storage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* FunctionBar */
.functionbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 998;
}

.functionbar .handlesbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  font: 24px arial;
  text-align: center;
  background: hsla(180, 0%, 0%, .75);
  word-spacing: 12px;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
       -o-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.functionbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: hsl(180, 0%, 90%);
}

.functionbar .active {
  color: #9cf;
}

.functionbar .hide {
  display: none;
}

/* Dialog Sec */
.functionbar .reveal {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.functionbar .reveal, .functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea {
  font-family: arial;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.functionbar input[type=text], .functionbar textarea, #change-selected-tag, #confirm-style {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000;
}

#dynamic-storage .selected {
  outline: 2px dotted #69f;
}

/* Addable Elements */
.functionbar .addcontent {
  text-align: center;
}

.functionbar .addcontent .element, .functionbar .editcontent .element {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.67);
  color: #262B2F;
}
.functionbar .element:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.functionbar .element .fa {
  font-size: 26px;
}
.functionbar .element h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/poly/css/application.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dynamic-storage">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__col--7">
          <div class="centered grid__col--8">
            <p>
              &nbsp;
            </p>
            <h1 class="headline-primary--grouped">Take a look at this amazing headline</h1>
            <h2 class="headline-secondary--grouped selected">Don't forget about the subtitle</h2>
            <p>This is a typical paragraph for the UI Kit. <a href="#">Here is what a link might look like</a>. The typical font family for this kit is Helvetica Neue.  This kit is intended for clean and refreshing web layouts. No jazz hands here, just the essentials to make dreams come true, with minimal clean web design. The kit comes fully equipped with everything from full responsive media styling to buttons to form fields. <em>I enjoy using italics as well from time to time</em>. Fell free to create the most amazing designs ever with this kit. I truly hope you enjoy not only the kit but this amazing paragraph as well. :)</p>
            <blockquote>You know what really gets me going? A really nice set of block quotes.  That's right, block quotes that say, "Hey, I'm an article you want to read and nurture."</blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid__col--4">
          <h4>Offcanvas Menu</h4>
          <div class="offcanvas">
            <span class="icn--close">
              <b class="srt">close</b>
            </span>
            <ul class="menu" role="navigation">
              <a class="menu__link" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="menu__link" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a class="menu__link" href="#">Link 3</a>
              <a class="menu__link--end" href="#">Link 4</a>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```